# Horizontal spry menu issues: in IE & javascript conflict

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, dreamweaver, spry

I have 3 problems with my website but i think they all may be related to the spry menu. Please take a look and see if you can offer me some advice, I would really appreciate it.

one: www.escapegardens.ie The spry seems to work fine on this page in safari, chrome & firefox but is messed up in IE7.
I have tried changing display to inline from block but then all messed up in safari & chrome
I have also tried adding this code given to me to beginning of layout.css file to clear padding etc - but just messes all text layout across other browsers:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
vertical-align: baseline; }
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block; }
body {
line-height: 1; }
ol, ul {
list-style: none; float: none; ©}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none; }
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0; }

 /* This helps to make newer HTML5 elements behave like DIVs in older browers */ 
article, aside, dialog, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, nav, section {
display:block;
}
```

Two: http://www.escapegardens.ie/Domestic_Garden_Landscaping.html & all other gallery pages, the spry is not laid out correctly as on the home page, the width of the menus are smaller.

Three: I have not been able to get the gallery pages e.g http://www.escapegardens.ie/Domestic_Garden_Landscaping.html to be centred on the browser as i have on the homepage.

I can send other information & code if it helps,

Many Thanks for you valuable time,

Jenny

Comment: Hi, I have resolved issue three but still having problems getting spry  to display properly in IE & also gallery page still displaying the spry menu incorrectly compared to the homepage. Any help welcome, many thanks Jenny

Comment: I have fixed this by changing:

Comment: I have fixed issue one i had with IE not displaying correctly by changing: f/loat to left in the following code: '/* HACK FOR IE: to stabilize appearance of menu items; the slash in float is to keep IE 5.0 from parsing */
@media screen, projection
{
 ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
 {
 display: inline;
 f\loat: left;
 background: #FFF;
 color: #CCC;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 height: 35px
 
 }
}'